# Overriding "Add user" header in django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

How can I change the text at the top of the add user page? I am talking about the text in this section:

[image]

I've been reading the docs and searching through the code, but I'm not finding the place to override this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This text is defined in the [`admin/auth/user/add_form.html`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/auth/user/add_form.html) template.  To override it create your own template with the same name in your project.

**EXAMPLE**:

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}

{% block content_title %}
    <h1>This is the title</h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block form_top %}
    <p>This is the subtitle</p>
{% endblock %}

{% block after_field_sets %}
<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("id_username").focus();</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What about the "Add user" text - that is not in that template.

Comment: This text is in the `content_title` block.  See the example in the updated answer.

Comment: I added this file, named add_form.html, to my apps admin/auth/user dir, and I added that dir to the TEMPLATE_DIRS in the settings file, and I bounced the webserver, but it not getting picked up. Is there something else I have to do?

Comment: You should create the `templates` dir in your project directory and add it to the `TEMPLATE_DIRS` setting (this is for django <= 1.7). And then create `admin/auth/user/add_form.html` inside this `templates` dir. As alternative you can create the `templates` dir inside one of your apps. In this case there is no need to set the `TEMPLATE_DIRS`.

Comment: I don't think the actual dir name matters, but I moved it to admin/templates/auth/user and I updated TEMPLATE_DIRS, but it's still not being picked up.

Comment: Nonono, path should be `<project_dir>/templates/admin/auth/user/add_form.html ` but only the `templates` part should be in the `TEMPLATE_DIRS`. Usual setting is: `TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'), )`

Comment: Code syntax in settings.py:

`TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'), ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]`